# Error handling using delegates

Tags: c#, error-handling, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I have a common method that I'm using to handle a specific error that may come back from a number of functions:

```
protected async Task<T> RunMyMethod<T>(Func<T> method)
{
    try
    {
        var returnValue = await Task.Run<T>(method);
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (MyCustomException)
    {
        // Force a clean shutdown of the software 
        ShutdownApplication();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how that is then used in a derived class:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> GetMyData()
{
    var returnValue = await base.RunMyMethod<IEnumerable<MyData>>(() =>
    {
        var returnval = GetMyDataFromServer();
        return returnval;
    });

    return returnValue;
}
```

When an exception of type `MyCustomException` occurs in `GetMyDataFromServer()` the software doesn't drop into the catch block.  I get the following error in the function `GetMyData()`:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception of type 'MyCustomException' was thrown.
```

This is with only User-unhandled exceptions turned on.

`GetMyDataFromServer()` communicates with a WCF service.  This service is what throws the error.

```
ChannelFactory<TChannel> cf = new ChannelFactory<TChannel>(endPointName);
Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);                    

var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();

. . .

channel = cf.CreateChannel();
var data = channel.CallWCFService();
```

Having looked around on-line, it appeared that the correct way to handle this was to change the base method as follows:

```
protected async Task<T> RunMyMethod<T>(Func<T> method)
{
    var returnValue = await Task.Run<T>(method).ContinueWith(e => 
    {                     
        ShutdownApplication();
        return default(T);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    return returnValue;
}
```

When I run this, I'm obviously not trapping for the correct error message, but I'm just getting a `TaskCancellationException`.

So, I have two questions:  is my conclusion about how to handle this exception correct and, if so, how do I trap a specific error; and why am I getting a `TaskCancellationException`?

Comment: Your code in `RunMyMethod` version 1 should work as expected. I mean it should catch `MyCustomException` and call `ShutdownApplication` if `GetMyDataFromServer` throws `MyCustomException`. Can you show the implementation of `GetMyDataFromServer`? Or can you post a [short but complete sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Can you add the code for `GetMyDataFromServer`.

Comment: For the purposes of this issue, `GetMyDataFromServer()` is just a function that throws a new `MyCustomException`

Comment: @pm_2 in that case `RunMyMethod` will catch it.

Comment: I've updated the question; although it does not appear to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `TaskCancellationException` because the continuation is cancelled as it's conditional (i.e. `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`) and the condition isn't met since the antecedent task wasn't faulted.

There's no reason to use that method of adding a continuation. Using `async-await` like you did at the start is good enough (and even simpler).

The issue is that you are trying to catch `MyCustomException` but that isn't the exception being thrown. Since you're using WCF the exception is `FaultException`. You can check the "real" exception stored in `FaultException.InnerException`.

Comment: I've updated the question.  There is no error handling in `GetMyDataFromServer`. The exception isn't being caught by the catch block

Comment: @pm_2 The only way there's an unhandled exception in `GetMyDataFromServer` that isn't caught by your code is that you run code in that method on a different thread. That's why we asked you to show the code.

Comment: I've updated the question with some additional information.  I don't believe that the error is thrown in a different thread (although it does come from a WCF service originally).

Comment: @pm_2 The exception isn't `MyCustomException`. Look at my update.

Comment: FaultException.InnerExcetion is null.  However, you are correct - that's why I wasn't catching the error.  Many thanks.